# Apex:MapInfoWindow issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to add the Account details like Name,Address etc  to locations list ? .
    How to display the  below records using   **apex:mapInfoWindow**  .
    Can anyone help me?

Vf Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!resultsAvailable}" title="Locations">
            <apex:map width="600px" height="400px">
                <apex:repeat value="{!locations}" var="pos">
                    <apex:mapMarker position="{!pos}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:map>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller:

```
        public with sharing class FindNearbyController {

    public List<Map<String,Double>> locations { get; private set; }

    public String currentPosition { 
        get {
            if (String.isBlank(currentPosition)) {
                currentPosition = '37.77493,-122.419416'; // San Francisco
            }
            return currentPosition;
        }
        set; 
    }

    public Boolean resultsAvailable {
        get {
            if(locations == Null) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public PageReference findNearby() {
        String lat, lon;

        // FRAGILE: You'll want a better lat/long parsing routine
        // Format: "<latitude>,<longitude>" (must have comma, but only one comma)
        List<String> latlon = currentPosition.split(',');
        lat = latlon[0].trim();
        lon = latlon[1].trim();

        // SOQL query to get the nearest warehouses
        String queryString =
           'SELECT Id, Name, Location__longitude__s, Location__latitude__s ' +
           'FROM Warehouse__c ' +
           'WHERE DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') < 20 ' +
           'ORDER BY DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION('+lat+','+lon+'), \'mi\') ' +
           'LIMIT 10';

        // Run the query
        List <Warehouse__c> warehouses = database.Query(queryString);

        if(0 < warehouses.size()) {
            // Convert to locations that can be mapped
            locations = new List<Map<String,Double>>();
            for (Warehouse__c wh : warehouses) {
                locations.add(
                    new Map<String,Double>{
                        'latitude' => wh.Location__latitude__s, 
                        'longitude' => wh.Location__longitude__s
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        else {
            System.debug('No results. Query: ' + queryString);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in the [apex:mapInfoWindow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_mapInfoWindow.htm) documentation, you will need to add the component to the markup:

```
<apex:mapMarker ...>
    <apex:mapInfoWindow>
        ...
    </apex:mapInfoWindow>
</apex:mapMarker>
```

and change content of each `locations` item to include the information you want to present.

**PS**

Per the comments:

```
public class Bean {
    public Map<String,Double> location;
    public Account account;
}

public List<Bean> locations { get; private set; }
```

and in the `findNearby` method:

```
       for (Warehouse__c wh : warehouses) {
            Bean b = new Bean();
            b.location = new Map<String,Double>{
                 'latitude' => wh.Location__latitude__s, 
                 'longitude' => wh.Location__longitude__s
            };
            // You need to add a reference to the correct Account here
            b.account = ...'
            locations.add(b);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, public List<Map<String,Double>> locations  is decalred like this. How to add Name to Locations?

Comment: @Mahesh You will have to introduce your own small Apex class that has a field that holds the `Map<String,Double>` and another field that holds the information you want to display in the marker e.g. a reference to an SObject.

Comment: can you please help me with some sample code, i am new to salesforce. I really struck here.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine for apex, but i was wondering on how we do the assignment in VF code.

Comment: can you please help me here

Comment: @Mahesh Please don't add multiple comments of this nature; we are all busy and prompting people to answer is pretty close to spamming them.

Comment: Ok sure, i will not repeat this in future. waiting for your response